# NetStream.Seek in red5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3, red5

I have one quick question.

Normally we use `NetStream.Seek` method but it will make the seek after the buffer area crossed the seek time length.(HTTP)

Can we seek the video that is beyond the buffered area like youtube in red5.

Will it start the buffer from the seek point.Please let me know.

If possible means give me some code sample(RTMP)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have a question or a test case.  `seek()` should work beyond the buffer.  However, you have to use a video format that allows this behavior, too.  Also, double-check that `inBufferSeek=false`.

[Adobe docs on NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html).